# Create Blue Folders in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am working on an existing project where there are some blue folders that store some image references. If I create normal yellow folders, images are not read. So how do I create new blue folders?

[image]

Comment: Note that if the images are not being read from your yellow folder, it will certainly be because you're using the wrong path or method call to load them. See my answer (not the accepted one but the topvoted one) here for a detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380842/uiimage-imagenamed-requires-pathforresource/12932540#12932540

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Drag the folder to your project and make sure you select **Create folder references for any added folders**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make blue folder you should do following steps,

1. Prepare folder structure with files in it.
2. Drag that folder into xcode i.e. project navigation pan.
3. Select " Create folder references for any added folders " option.
4. Finally click to add.

You will get that folder with blue color.

Thank You..