# Issue while integrating with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking-2

I am facing an issue while integrating with AFNetworking (for the first time). I needed to support iOS 6 so I downloaded AFNetworking 2.5.4 framework.

After downloading, I dragged and dropped AFNetworking folder into my project, choose the right targets and selected the option **Copy items if needed**.

Then in one of my implementation file, I started typing import statement and Xcode showed me all AFNetworking related files and I selected `AFNetworking.h` to add `#import "AFNetworking.h"` statement.

But, to my surprise, I am getting following compilation error saying `AFNetworking.h file not found`.

Any idea what am I missing here?

PS: 
1. I do not want to go via Submodule git or Cocoa Pods way.
2. Tried by cleaning the project and re-build.
3. Tried by importing the module - `@import AFNetworking`.

[image]

Here is how it looks when I add the AFNetworking folder:

[image]

Comment: try `@import AFNetworking;` once

Comment: Already tried; no luck!

Comment: Is the AFNetworking folder you dragged in to the project is blue in colour?

Comment: Yes @JimTierney it is blue. Attaching the screenshot.

Comment: its means is not added properly , delete and add againonce

Comment: see once this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346247/xcode-project-navigator-difference-between-yellow-folder-and-blue-folder and this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374133/create-blue-folders-in-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the files you have dragged over (as a complete folder) have not all been mapped with Xcode.

A fix (*though there will be quicker solutions than this*), is that you **manually create your folders** in your project **matching** the folder names within the `AFNetworking` folders, and drag the actual group of **class files** into each of your own folders. (delete the initially aded blue folder first.)

Although it's a pain, and realise not the quickest solution, though in the meantime this *will* fix it.
I hope this helps

Jim

Comment: Thanks much Jim. It worked with manual folder creation! Guess a bug that needs a fix.