# How to simulate directory/grouping path in my Xcode project when loading image or other assets?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is how my Xcode project is structured.

[image: This is how my Xcode project is structured.]

To access the `bs-better@2x.png` file, I can use the following code:

```
UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bs-better"];
```

This already works. However, for readability sake, I would like it if there's a way to include the grouping path in the code, something like:

```
UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets/Icons/bs/bs-better"];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Well answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380842/uiimage-imagenamed-requires-pathforresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, for this you need to create physical directory rather then logical [image]

You have to add directory with "create folder references for any added folders" rather then "Create group for any added folders" so it will generate physical directory like "Example Directory" in below image, so it must be access by proper path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bs-better" ofType:@"png"]];
```

This is the method to get files from bundle.